# Where does this validation popup come from?

Tags: validation, internet-explorer, firefox, model-view-controller

I've got my own validation but this popup overrides it for an invalid email. I want to use my own.

How do I disable it?

Firefox:
[image]

IE:
[image]

code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.mForgottenLogin.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "txtEmail" , @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mForgottenLogin.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger ErrorBackgroundHighlight" })
```

Code from inspector:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-email="Please enter a valid email address" data-val-required="The email address is required" id="txtEmail" name="mForgottenLogin.Email" value="" type="email">
```

Comment: Change your input type from email to text

Comment: added change and it worked thank you, was driving me nuts.

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mForgottenLogin.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "txtEmail" , @class = "form-control", @type="text" } })

Comment: please add your answer

Comment: Happy, that it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input type from **email** to **text**.

From : `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.mForgottenLogin.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "txtEmail" , @class = "form-control" } })>`

To : `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.mForgottenLogin.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "txtEmail" , @class = "form-control" , @type= "text" } })`